# Run a single spec with grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gruntjs

How would I, on the command-line, specify a single specfile to run when using grunt-contrib-jasmine? My jasmine section looks something like:

```
jasmine: {
  myapp: {
    src: [ 'src/base.js', 'src/**/*.js' ]
  },
  options: {
    spec: [
      'spec/models/**/*.js',
      'spec/views/**/*.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

I just want to run the tests for `spec/models/file1.js`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somebody has done this for you with a `--filter` command line argument, though it hasn't been pulled into master yet:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/pull/70

> **filename**
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter=foo` will run spec files that have foo in their file name.
>
> **folder**
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter=/foo` will run spec files within folders that have foo* in their name.
>
> **wildcard**
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter=/*-bar` will run anything that is located in a folder *-bar
>
> **comma separated filters**
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter=foo,bar` will run spec files that have foo or bar in their file name.
>
> **flags with space**
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter="foo bar"` will run spec files that have foo bar in their file name.
>
> `grunt jasmine --filter="/foo bar"` will run spec files within folders that have foo bar* in their name.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've added a comment to the pull-request expressing support for merging it.

Comment: This has been merged!

Answer (score 4):

Chris Wren has written a blog post on [Advanced Grunt Tooling](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224213905/http://chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling), under the section [Running individual test specs](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224213905/http://chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling#Running-individual-test-specs), he lists an example which allows for naming the spec you would like to run from the command line.

Comment: These links are now dead. I spent a few minutes trying to track down the originals but they seem to be behind auth: http://dev.chrisawren.com/posts/Advanced-Grunt-tooling

Comment: @internetross thanks for the heads up and attempt to revive the links. I found them via the internet archive. Once again a good reason to donate to them :)